# Is their any way to identify whether the miner is using renewable or non renewable energy for mining?

Tags: blockchain, mining-hardware

Is their any way to identify whether the miner is using renewable or non renewable energy for mining ? in decentralized way?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible. Energy sources are not part of the blockchain.